# Microsoft Excel - Re-setting cell values to 0 every time file is opened

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have created a file that runs a few simple calculations for users based on inputs from cells B8:B15. All other cells are locked to users.

The problem I have is that the aforementioned input cells need to be re-set to 0 every time a user opens the file (the file is saved on Microsoft Teams and I do not want user to use each other's inputs).

Thank you in advance for any helpful advice!

Comment: You can write a VBA macro that will automatically run on opening the file.

Comment: Why do you save the spreadsheet if you want it to be reinitialized on every open?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this [Link](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4858-excel-clear-cell-on-open-exit.html) to insert VBA code that will clear the cell range on a specific worksheet each time the file is open or closed.

Per suggested comments, the information below is from the website that explains how this is done, "www.extendoffice.com"

"Please do as follows to clear specified cell contents on workbook open and exit.
Firstly, you need to save the workbook which you need to clear specified cell contents on open or exit as an Excel Macro-enabled Workbook.

1. Please click **File** > **Save As** > **Browse**. See screenshot:

[image]

2. In the **Save As** dialog box, please select a folder to save the workbook, enter a new name into the **File name** box as you need, select **Excel Macro-Enabled Workbook** from the **Sava as type** drop-down list, and then click the **Save** button.

[image]

3. In the popping up **Microsoft Excel** dialog box, please click the **OK** button as below screenshot shown.

[image]

4. Open the Macro-Enabled Workbook you have saved just now, press the **Alt + F11** keys to open the **Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications** window.
5. In the **Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications window**, double click **ThisWorkbook** in the left pane, and then copy below VBA code into the Code window.

**VBA code 1: Clear specified cell contents on workbook open**

1    Private Sub Workbook_Open()
2    'Updated by Extendoffice 20190712
3        Application.EnableEvents = False
4            Worksheets("test").Range("A1:A11").Value = ""
5        Application.EnableEvents = True
6    End Sub  ,br/>

**VBA code 2: Clear specified cell contents on workbook exit**

1    Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
2    'Updated by Extendoffice 20190712
3        Worksheets("test").Range("A1:A11").Value = ""
4    End Sub

**Note**: In the above codes, test, and A1:A11 is the worksheet name and cell range you will clear contents from.  Please change them as you need.

6. Press the **Alt** + **Q** keys to exit the **Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications** window.

From now on, when opening or closing the workbook, specified cell contents in certain worksheet will be cleared automatically."

Comment: It is advisable that you post the steps/code here as the link might change in the future.

Comment: This solved it, thanks!